# Symfony2 interaction between forms, problems if validation fails

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have 2 forms which display the following:
[image]

They are created dynamically, not from entities.

My controller is the following:

```
<?php
...create the relevant array $rolesListForForm 
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()->getForm(); //create empty form

$HRsInThisProject = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findUsersByProject($prj);

foreach ($HRsInThisProject as $key => $HR)
    {
    $form->add('roleOf_'.$key, 'choice', array('choices'   => $rolesListForForm, 'required'  => true, 'data' => $HR['role'], 'label' => false, ));
    $form->add('isActive_'.$key, 'choice', array('choices'   => [0 => 'Inactive', 1 => 'Active'] , 'required'  => true, 'data' => $HR['is_active'], 'label' => false, ));
    }

...create the relevant array $HRsInMyDomainForForm 

$form->add('showinactive', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Show inactive users', 'required'  => false, 'data' => true, ));
$form->add('HRid', 'choice', array('choices' => $HRsInMyDomainForForm,'required' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Choose a resource', 'label' => false, ));
$form->add('role', 'choice', array('choices' => $rolesListForForm,'required' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Choose a role', 'label' => false, ));            
$form->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));     

$form->handleRequest($request);

// If form is valid
if ($form->isValid()) 
    {
    ...lots of logic here to understand if persisting or not stuff on DB, then I simply refresh the current page
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('hr_manage', array('projectID' => $prj->getId())));
    }

//creation of the second form
$formGlobalSearch=$this->createFormBuilder()
->add('username', 'text', array('constraints' => new UsernameExists()))
->add('role', 'choice', array('choices' => $rolesListForForm,'required' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Choose a role', 'label' => false, ))
->add('submitUsername', 'submit', array('label' => 'Search username globally'))
->getForm();

$formGlobalSearch->handleRequest($request);

if ($formGlobalSearch->isValid())
    {
        //persist stuff on DB and refresh current page
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('hr_manage', array('projectID' => $prj->getId())));
    }

return $this->render('HR/show.html.twig', array('projectID' => $prj->getId(), 'hrlist' => $HRsInMyDomain, 'form' => $form->createView(), 'HRs' => $HRsInThisProject, 'formGlobalSearch' => $formGlobalSearch->createView(),));
```

It all works smoothly, the only problem occurs when the second form throws a validation error. When it does the top form is not properly rendered anymore, I see stuff like this:

[image]

Here is the relevant part of the twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.showinactive) }}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>User ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Role</td>
    <td>Started</td>
    <td>Status</td>
</tr>

{% for key, HR in HRs %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ key }}</td>
    <td>{{ HR.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_row(form['roleOf_' ~ key]) }}</td>
    <td>{{ HR.started_at|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_row(form['isActive_' ~ key]) }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<br>
Add new resource:
{{ form_row(form.HRid) }}{{ form_row(form.role) }}
{{ form_row(form.save) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
<br>
Or you can search for a user of ProJacked at global level
{{ form_start(formGlobalSearch) }}
{{ form_errors(formGlobalSearch) }}
{{ form_widget(formGlobalSearch) }}
{{ form_end(formGlobalSearch) }}
```

Any idea?

Comment: why not create a custom form type and call it passing you HRsInThisProject-like argurments instead of doing stuff in the controller. It might give you more control over validation and etc.

Comment: Agreed - you should separate each form into its own class so it can be handled individually and have everything you need for each form encompassed in that class.

Comment: Instead of the foreach ($HRsInThisProject, you should be using a form collection type.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.  I can't tell from your posted code why your user list is getting corrupted when the form is posted but I suspect your logic of 'roleOf_'.$key has an error in it somewhere.  Using a collection will simplify things significantly.

Comment: I'll try creating the for classes (I did not as I use this forms only here). I don't think the problem is on the foreach etc..., as I have the same problem on the "showinactive" field which is a simple checkbox (you see from the example that it loses the tickmark)

Comment: JasonRoman and Sebastien: it worked! I don't understand why but it worked, thank you.

Comment: @Cerad thank you for the tip. I'm sure it would make my code more elegant. I'll keep your suggestion in mind in case I have to do something similar in the future!